# Intermittent Network Share Speeds

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, performance

I have a 2008 Server box that is running file sharing between 2 Apple G5's.  When I try to upload a file say one that is 500 MB.  The upload will start, immediately jump to about 60 megs, slows down on the transfer down to 0 for a few seconds, then picks back up to full transfer rate, then repeats the cycle for the rest of the transfer.  Any ideas on what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that the G5's and Server 2008's TCP stacks aren't able to stabilize the connection. This typically a tcp-windowing fault of some kind. Microsoft rewrote the Windows TCP/IP stack with Server 2008, and that has caused various issues with older TCP/IP stacks, such as with your G5's and whatever OSX version they're running. Laying blame is tricky here since there are many ways to build a TCP/IP stack.

You may be able to tell the Windows IP stack to behave differently enough that transfers are speedy. Unfortunately, I don't the exact magic sauce that'll make it work for 10.4 or 10.5.